# How to tell Nginx to not rewrite URL's in selected location

Tags: nginx, php, rewrite, url

I am writing some PHP CMS code with a clean url implementation in Nginx.  To improve security of my code I want to rewrite all of the requests in my root directory `/` using the following type:

```
rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1 last;
```

With this kind of rewrite the rest of the php scripts will not be accessible from the user's side (they will be only, if included in php, am I right?).  However, I do not want to rewrite the request in one location (for mi that will me `/static/`), because I will be serving only static content such as images and css from that location.  How can I make this rewrite not work in certain locations?

Comment: Show the entire `server` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Understanding and using the `location` directive should solve your problem. When location is followed only by a prefix string (i.e. without modifiers such as '=', or '~*'), the longest prefix string is matched first. For example:

```
server {
    server_name example.org;
    root /var/www/site;

    location / {
        # Configuration A
    }

    location /static {
        # Configuration B
    }
```

In this configuration, the URL `example.org/static/foo.gif` would match Configuration B because the prefix string `/static` is longer than `/`. Meanwhile, `example.org/index.php?q=bar` would match Configuration A because that is the only match.

You could then have Configuration A serve up content with PHP, while Configuration B serves static content.

Also, I would highly recommend reading through the [Nginx Pitfalls](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/) page, if you haven't already. It addresses some issues that are highly relevant in your situation, such as taxing rewrites, using fastcgi_pass safely, and so forth.

Comment: So rewrite conditions used in / will not work in /static ?

Comment: In this configuration, yes. Any given URL will match only one location. There is a lot more to the location directive than I've presented. For a full explanation of its matching algorithm, read the following: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location

Comment: and am I wright with that, with rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1 last; rewrite any files (excluding index.php) will not be accesible? And will then they work, when I will include them in PHP?

Comment: It depends on your complete server configuration, and how PHP FastCGI is configured.